# Как сделать проверку на изменение значения в файле json?

Tags: python, json, telegram-bot, aiogram

значение переменно parsText1 может не измениться. Чтоб не спамить одним и тем же сообщением, нужно как то сверить, не одно и то же ли я хочу отправить, как это можно реализовать?

```
postText = read('translate_data.json')
parsText1 = postText['twitt'][0]['translate_text']

@db.message_handler()
async def send_text(message: types.Message):
    while True:
        for chat_id in config["CHANNEL_LOGIN"]:
            await bot.send_message(chat_id, parsText1)
        time.sleep(350)
```

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Так он у тебя тупо зависнет на 350 секунд, юзай хотя бы `asyncio.sleep()`

Comment: Понял, спасибо, а как проверку сделать?)

Comment: Ну так просто откройте файл и проверьте, в чем проблема?

Comment: Можно пожалуйста пример в коде? Можно пример на проверке изменение переменной просто показать